# Database table not created after running php artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 5.7 and I noticed that my database table was not created after running php artisan migrate even when my .env has been properly updated and everything seems very correct from my angle.

After much research, I stumbled into a video that said I have to go to AppServiceProver.php and add some lines of codes as follows:

Update AppServiceProver.php from:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
       //
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
```

To:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers; 

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
```

A line of code was added on line 6 (use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;) and the Schema was called upon on line 17 (Schema::defaultStringLength(191);).

Immediately I added those lines of codes to my AppServiceProver.php, and then ran *php artisan migrate*; all my table just got created immediately on my database.

But the unfortunate thing for me as a learner is that the man said he doesn't know why the tables were not created at first and why the codes had to be added to *AppServiceProvider.php*. That he had the error and stumbled into the answer too.

As a learner, I am curious and want to know why I had that challenge and why those lines of codes solved them.

Thank you very much for your kind answers.

Comment: what about your DB? What version and etc.?

Comment: @Sam O, firstly delete migration file and tables in your target DB, and run again `php artisan migrate` because your migration file already made when you first tried. check this link...https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error  good luck!

Comment: @autumnrustle, I am using XAMPP Control Panel v 3.2.2

Comment: I think problem in your DB. Some DB have max length of char and varchar fields less then 255. So you can in all migrations set length of this fields less then 255. Or you can set it by default (like yor do)

Comment: to reload all migrations you can use `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Answer (score 1):

You have to set defaultStringLength to switch the character set, utf8mb4 
The utf8mb4 character set is useful because nowadays we need support for storing not only language characters but also symbols, newly introduced emojis, and so on. Hope you got it!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply While running the migration you may get the error as

```
Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

this is because

```
Just For Example
```

You Migration may look

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

While running the migration it will look for length for the each field

such as

```
public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name',50);
                $table->string('email',100)->unique();
                $table->timestamp('email_verified_at',150)->nullable();
                $table->string('password',150);
                $table->rememberToken();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
```

If you are lazy and need to add comman length to add all the fileds

use `\Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` inside `boot`  Method of `AppServiceProvider`

By Adding this IT will add the length of the fileds as `191`

Thats it

Comment: Thank you for the explanation